# Qt Tree Model versus nested maps for storing a dictionary for translations

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a class using Qt that needs to import a dictionary that will be used to look up a command and build a command sentence. The commands are arranged in a hierarchical manner and have a corresponding hex key and value definition. For illustration purposes, it could look like this:

```
01 : Volume
        | - 01 : Step : 00=Down, 01=Up
        | - 02 : Set : ceil(255/100 * x)
02 : Power
        | - 01 : Power : 00=Off, 01=On
        | - 02 : Sleep : ...etc
```

I want to load this dictionary and then be able to search it for "Volume/Set/50" and return the command sentence "01 02 80" or look up "01 02 80" and return "Volume/Set/50."

The actual implementation is a little more complex and has commands at different levels in the tree structure and could include any number and combination of commands from different levels in a single sentence.

**Edit:**

The comment provided by volodymyr below introduces a concept (Trie) that I was not familiar with. It may be the best implementation for this particular scenario, but I have to research it some more.  I am still interested in an answer to my original question (with the addition of Trie):

***What are the advantages and disadvantages of using each of these methods for this implementation?***

- Qt Tree Model
- Nested Maps
- Trie

**Original question: (for context)**

Would a Qt Tree Model, nested maps or some other means be better suited to store the dictionary?  I realize "better" may be subjective, but I would like to know the trade offs.

I am already building a Qt Tree Model to display some other data in a QTreeView, so that code will already exist and could easily be used. Would the Tree Model allow more flexibility in loading dictionaries with different structures? Is there a better way to do this? or maybe a standard design pattern?

Comment: In case of dictionaries for natural languages, trie data structure can be used(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation). Maybe it will be useful for you.

Comment: After researching Tries, it appears as though it would be useful for finding the hex keys associated with a word (encoding), but wouldn't provide the capability to easily convert a hex sentence back to a word (decoding). Would it be appropriate to build a Qt Tree Model of the data and then build a Trie to index the location of the keys for encoding, then just iterate through the Qt Tree Model to perform the decoding function?

Comment: I can't say anything about efficiency of such approach, but the fact that you already have some code that can be reused makes me think that you should try it. Anyway, as you mentioned, in case of Trie you'll need some helper structure like TreeModel to allow reverse translation. Also, it seems like during translation to hex you need to perform some actions on supplied arguments(like ceil(255/100 * x)). You should take it in account, because in this case it isn't just direct translation. In case if there was direct conformance between hex and string representation two way hash could be used.

Comment: Thanks. My intention is to run any calculations or functions needed for translation using the QtScript module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the number of items at each level in the command tree is too small to justify using a trie.  A trie (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), due to its large branching factor, is best for a large number of items -- for example a natural-language dictionary, as volodymyr has pointed out.

In fact, the number may be too small to justify even std::map.  If there aren't more than a couple dozen commands or codes at a given point in the tree, a linear search is probably about as fast as a search in a map, or faster.  The memory representation as a vector or list would also be more compact.  That said, std::map's interface seems very well suited for what you're trying to do, so, in practice, it's probably still the best choice overall.

I can't see how QTreeModel can be better than std::map from any point of view (speed, memory, ease of use), except that it may mesh better with the rest of your code, since it's Qt-based.  However, if you even vaguely suspect that this part may have a use without Qt, I would not hesitate to choose the standard library stuff (std::map).  The only truly compelling reason to choose QTreeModel over std::map would be if you actually used it in a QTreeView.

Comment: another point of interest: there is a QMap in Qt which is implemented as a skip-list, it has the advantage of both being integrated with Qt and giving good performance with small numbers of items whilst incurring little overhead. Nested QMaps would certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

Qt TreeModels are optimised to work with TreeViews and are good for sorting etc. They aren't really mean't for random access bidirectional mapping.

Nested Maps will be optimised for translating in one direction. To go back and forwards efficiently you really need to mirror the maps separately for forwards and backwards translation.

Build it with std::maps. profile it and optimise it if you need to.